# Configure how much the volume increases with each keystroke in winamp

Tags: windows, audio, winamp

Currently, my winamp only increases the volume by 1 ou 2% each time I press the volume up key. How can I change that behaviour? I couldn't find it in the settings.

thanks

ANSWER:
I've found out the answer. I created a hotkey script that sends 5 times the command ctrl+alt+u, whenever I press ctrl+alt+uparrow. Then configured winamp to increase the volume with the ctrl+alt+u shortcut. Here's the script:

^!u::
       send {ctrl}{alt}{uparrow}
       send {ctrl}{alt}{uparrow}
       send {ctrl}{alt}{uparrow}
       send {ctrl}{alt}{uparrow}
       send {ctrl}{alt}{uparrow}
return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to build an AutoHotkey script that will detect when the player window of Winamp is active and transform keystrokes from the up and down arrow keys to multiple keystrokes.

Comment: If it works that'd be perfect, but I don't know how to map one hotkey into multiple instances of a hotkey.

Comment: I marked this answer as the accepted one because it most resemblees the solution I found.

Comment: Woot. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

I use [volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) from Nirsoft to control volume using alt+scroll. This has a facility to change the step size. This will do what you want, but not within Winamp. Any good?

Comment: Unfortunately I want to manage winamp specifically. Basically, I want to control music volume while in-game without affecting the master volume.

Answer (score 0):

Winamp at it's current version 5.56, does not have a preference to set what the "step size" of a volume up/down action is, few media applications do.

An alternative to allow you dial the volume up or down quicker is to use the mouse scroll wheel for volume, or a media keyboard with a dial you can rotate quickly up or down.

Or checkout some [Winamp plug-ins](http://www.winamp.com/plugins) that have more presets; [HotKey Plugin](http://www.winamp.com/plugins/details/50543) for example has options for volume presets, binding keys to set volume levels.

Comment: I'll try to look into the plugins.